# How to transform first character of a line to uppercase with VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

How to transform first character of a line to uppercase with VSCode ?

`hello world!` -> `Hello world!`

I just saw these two options:

1. Transform to Title Case
2. transform to Lowercase

Comment: in c# or which language?

Comment: You can try this addon: https://github.com/wmaurer/vscode-change-case for this

Comment: @RajdeepDebnath With https://code.visualstudio.com

Comment: I know, vsode is an editor it's not a file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find:

```
^(.)
```

And replace by:

```
\u$1
```